Excluding symlinked directories from VScode/Python analyzers
I have used ln -s ../a/b to get the directory b to the ./c/b path in my workspace for convenience. Adding the **/c/b/** entry to the following exclusion lists:

Files: Watcher Exclude
Files: Exclude
Search: Exclude
Python › Analysis: Exclude

still results in the following error while working with the files under a/b (while never explicitly opening ./c/b).

Pressing 'Compare', on the left side there is nonetheless a file from ./c/b. Naturally, there are no changes for comparison, since both files refer to a single one.
I'm wondering how to ensure files from ./c/b are never watched for by VScode/Python tools and the error is not popping up?
